# Meaning of 'rundown'

Tags: vocabulary

I have a sentence,

> Here's a rundown on/of the activities of our ten biggest competitors.

The meaning of rundown is  'a detailed report' which I cannot interpret intuitively.

if the slang means 'supporting' I can discern easier as supporting somebody a bridge to rundown from a dilemma.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rundown), it explains in baseball which is difficult for non-native speakers without that sports in majority.

in [Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rundown),

> in baseball, 1908, from verbal phrase, from run (v.) + down (adv.). Meaning "list of entries in a horse race and the odds" is from 1935; slang generalized sense of "summary, account, list of information or facts" is from 1945.

What's the story about the extending of slang 'rundown'

Comment: Why the difficulty in comparing "list of entries in a horse race and the odds" with the later  "summary, account, list of information or facts" - both lists you run your eyes down

Comment: It's difficult to understand from run+down to 'list'

Comment: It is a well known and used idiom: "To run down a list" or "To run your eyes down a list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *run* can mean to perform a procedure to completion (probably derived from a person running around a predetermined course), and often suggests something composed of a number of detailed steps which must be done in order.  Hence why computer programs are said to *run* and why there are phrases like *run this through the machine,* *run it through our process*, etc.

*Run down X* when X is a list means to go through each item in the list.  Many lists are vertically arranged bulleted or numbered items, so "down" is associated with "completed."

A *rundown* (noun form) is a list created by going through each or every of something, later expected to be gone through item by item in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

While I understand run down in the context you have given, I'm wondering what the run down actually looks like.

If it is actually a list of activities that have an order then run down would be appropriate. However if

a) there is no obvious order

or

b) it's a little bit more than a list, i.e. there are some explanatory notes explaining the activities

then I would use:

**[Break down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_down)** - *to divide into parts to give more details, to provide a more indepth analysis of.*

Here is a **break down** of the activities of our ten biggest competitors.